# How to determine when Mapbox GL JS FlyTo has "arrived"

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'd like to show an overlay when the Mapbox flyto camera movement has completed its action, and is in place at the correct position and zoom level.  Is there a way to know when that action is complete?

So, fly to a position and then show the overlay, basically.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can achieve this by combining a few map event listeners and a variable as follows.

To prevent a tooltip when the user has moved or zoomed the map by mouse or keyboard you will need a variable that determines wheter your user clicked the "fly" button or not:

```
map.on('flystart', function(){
    flying = true;
});
map.on('flyend', function(){
    flying = false;
});
```

Then this code will execute once your map has stopped moving and zooming:

```
map.on('moveend', function(e){
   if(flying){
      // tooltip or overlay here
      map.fire(flyend); 
   }
});
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ft7s8son/

Comment: Doh.  I looked at that list of events and never saw moveend.  Thank you!

Comment: Dude, I really appreciate it! This works great!

Comment: "flystart/end" events appear to have been removed in mapbox-gl-js 2+, but you can still do a map.once('moveend',()=>{}) before the flyTo or other call and capture the final location-